# Find the matrix product when possible

Tags: matrices

$\begin{bmatrix}-1& 3\\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}0& -2 & 4\\ 1 & -3 & 2\end{bmatrix} $

I realized that there is no third matrix column so does that mean I assume three zeros?

Comment: No you use normal matrix multiplication

Comment: The result will be a 2*3 matrix like on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted my first post since it looks so lengthy. Straightforward I.E. here.

The end matrix will look like the 2 by 3 matrix there. So let's compute the upper lefthand number.

That number, 0, is in the first row and first column. So the row we are working with is the first row:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 3  \end{pmatrix}$$

The column is  the first column: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Do you see this?

So the process for this case is $-1\cdot(0) + 3\cdot(1)$.

On to the next number, $-2$. What row and column are we working with?
Once you understand that, mimic the process above for every number.

understand?

Comment: Thanks for the edit once again. ;^; no idea how to put that on there.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! I edited your post to display formulas. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might be helpful for future posts. Also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) offers a lot of symbols and shows you the latex code. :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you kept on explaining this to me. Finally I figured it out. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

$AB$ is defined whenever $A$ is $m \times k$ and $B$ is $k \times n$ for some integers $k,m,n$. The resulting matrix $C\equiv(c_{ij})$ is $m\times n$.

In particular, $c_{ij}=\sum_{k} a_{ik}b_{kj}$.

These matrices are $2 \times 2$ and $2 \times 3$. Can you use the above to come to a conclusion?

Comment: No, I cannot. Not yet anyway.

Comment: Tell us what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Well, I tried -1(0)+3(1) like mathflair said but I still do not get it. For instance, the order does not have a flow to it.

Comment: Ugh, this is frustrating.

Comment: Youtube might be a good place to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYlOjyPyX3g

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will watch it and see if I can apply it to this problem.

Comment: Okay, I have came to a conclusion. I do not know if this is right but here is what I got \begin{bmatrix}3& -7 & 2\\ 4 & -18 & 20\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yes! That looks right! Good job! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the first matrix had a third column, then you wouldn't be able to multiply. "Row times column" requires that the numbermof columns in the first matrix agrees with the number of rows in the second one.